# FileReader() inside Vue computed property does not work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, filereader

I am trying to render a series of image thumbnails based on images that I drag onto the screen.

My data looks like this:

```
data() {
  return {
    files: [File1, File2, File3]
  }
}
```

...where each `File` is a `blob`.

Here is my `computed` property, that should just return me each `File` `blob`s result

```
thumbnails() {
  return files.map(file => {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

     return reader.result
  })
}
```

I then try to render on screen as:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="thumbnail in thumbnails>
    <img :src="thumbnail">
  </li>
</ul>
```

It doesn't work.

What is extremely interesting, however, is that if I insert a breakpoint in the `files.map(...)`, it does work! What am I missing?

Comment: `readAsDataURL` is asynchronous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What am I missing?

The fact that `FileReader.readAsDataURL()` method is *asynchronous*.

I'd recommend you to rethink your flow, or you can use [`vue-async-computed`](https://github.com/foxbenjaminfox/vue-async-computed) package.

Using it you can write it liked this:

```js
{
  asyncComputed: {
    thumbnails() {
      return Promise.all(this.files.map((file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const reader = new FileReader();
          // handle success
          reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(reader.result);
          }, false);
          // handle error
          reader.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject();
          }, false);
          // reading file
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });
      }));
    },
  }
}
```

Don't forget that until `Promise.all` is resolved the `thumbnails` will be `null`, so you should add check for that to your template.